# Can I place a cap on my furnace exhaust to keep rainwater out?

Tags: furnace

I have a Lennox high efficiency furnace the vents out the roof with plastic piping,  both fresh air and exhaust. The fresh air pipe terminates above the roof with a U-shaped pipe at the end of it, I presume to keep out moisture.
The exhaust pipe on the other hand just terminates with an open pipe facing skyward.

The problem we have is moisture and insects hit the open end , runs down inside the pipe until it collects in the exhaust blower in the furnace . 
We have to have a serviceman out approx. every 4 months to unclog the drains , and remove water from the blower.

Can we put a raincap or u-shaped piping on the end of the exhaust pipe? The serviceman says its just a problem with these furnaces that vent thru the roof.

Comment: Is replacing the dodgy venting an option? Plastic vent pipes on combustion appliances are a known hazard...

Comment: Not true, TPE. Every high-efficiency furnace I've ever seen has PVC venting, and we know furnaces up here in the frozen north.

Comment: @isherwood -- I suspect that people get away with it more often for furnaces due to the HX efficiency drops with filter clogging being less than when a water heater scales up, but it's definitely a [known](https://www.phcppros.com/articles/1911-is-pvc-an-acceptable-vent-material-for-flue-gases) [hazard](https://www.phcppros.com/articles/1912-pvc-flue-pipe-failure)

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like more of a drain problem than anything. These condensing furnaces are designed to condense and drain if rain gets in the flue, it just flows through the unit to the drain. I almost think without looking at it, that if you have a 1/2 inch drain I would change to a 3/4 in. drain. Putting a cap on top creates other problems like restrictions at flue, which could potentially be deadly if there is a malfunction. Also if you are in a cold climate you might want to insulate the drain so it doesn't freeze up on cold days as well.

Answer (score 3):

"These furnaces". LOL. It is a poor carpenter who blames his hammer.

I'd put a 45 degree elbow on it, pointing away from the intake duct and the roof (or any other structure). From that elbow add a short length of pipe with a 45 degree angle on it (or another 45 elbow), resulting in a vertical exit face orientation. Should keep 95% of the rain out without undue restriction.

You could also just add a 90 degree elbow, but that may not clear your roof as well. [This question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/12561/do-i-need-a-rain-snow-cover-on-this-furnace-vent) shows how vents protruding from walls are set up the same.

<sub>Disclaimer: I'm not an HVAC technician nor a code expert. I do have gobs of home construction and remodeling experience, as well as two decades of home ownership and improvement. This is what I'd do. YMMV.</sub>

Comment: I agree with both. The exhaust fan be oriented to reduce rain intake, but if that's being a serious problem you need to check the condensate drain system as well. I've seen the latter slip out of position and keep water from draining, which will cause mysterious malfunctions until corrected.